# Getting blank fields after inserting new records with mysql_real_escape_string successfully

Tags: php, mysql

I insert new records to a MySQL database/table using PHP and every thing is fine. Collation of DB and tables are utf8_unicode_ci. Here is the insertion code:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = "POST") 
{
    $category = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);

    mysql_connect('localhost', 'xxx','xxxx') or die(mysql_error()); //Connect to server
    mysql_select_db('xxxx') or die("Cannot connect to database"); //Connect to database

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO categories (category) VALUES ('$category')"); //SQL query
    header("location: home.php");
}
else
{
    header("location:home.php"); //redirects back to home
}
```

I create same database in my hosting service, I use WAMP/phpMyAdmin/Export + data. Every thing looks fine in my hosting/phpMyAdmin and the records are there in tables. Collations are the same.
**BUT** when I try to insert a record, the new text fields are blank, I have a new record with new id but text field content is empty. No error message. There is a warning:

> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'yyyy'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/yyyyyy/public_html/xxxxx/add.php on line 12

'yyyy' is a different name from xxxx in mysql_select_db('xxxx') that I do not know where is it coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if $category is null

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ==  "POST" && isset($_POST['category'])) 
{
    $category = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);

    mysql_connect('localhost', 'xxx','xxxx') or die(mysql_error()); //Connect to server
    mysql_select_db('xxxx') or die("Cannot connect to database"); //Connect to database

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO categories (category) VALUES ('$category')"); //SQL query
    //header("location: home.php");
    echo 'successful'
}
else
{
    //header("location:home.php"); //redirects back to home
    echo 'problem'
}
```

Also fix:

```
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = "POST")
```

To

```
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
```

Comment: I corrected the code as you suggested but no difference. It is working in WAMP correctly anyway. How could I use var_damp()? I tested 'echo vat_damp....' but Couldn't see any results. Sorry newbie!

Comment: Ok, It returns success and adds empty text records.

Comment: Can you add your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Try this `mysql_query("INSERT INTO categories (category) VALUES ('" . $category . "')");`

Answer (score 0):

I simply brought these two line befor  mysql_real_escape_string

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'xxx','xxxx') or die(mysql_error()); //Connect to server
mysql_select_db('xxxx') or die("Cannot connect to database"); //Connect to database


$category = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);
```

and it is working fine!